# Vuetify dialog: Is there a "small" & "large" equivalent of Bootstrap dialog?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm learning Vuetify, coming from Bootstrap. I got to dialogs and got them working nicely.

However, in the docs, it says `width` or `max-width` props also take strings.

I tried and it seems css width measurements work: both  numbers (px) worked and percentages too. Didn't go further because I stopped at this logical "measurement" I'm used to from Bootstrap: I'd like to set the dialog to be "small" or "large", as in Bootstrap.

I have found that `width` also takes "unset" as parameter, but I couldn't find any documentation on what other constants it takes.

So, are there any "large" , "small" equivalents? Or documentation showing the possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vuetify `v-dialog` component there are no direct analogues of "large" and "small". But you can simply make it by yourself.

By example, you can create some global variables:

```js
Vue.prototype.$dialogSmall = 300;
Vue.prototype.$dialogLarge = 800;
```

Ant then use it in your `v-dialog` component:

```js
<v-dialog
  v-model="dialog"
  :width="$dialogSmall"
  :max-width="$dialogSmall"
>
  ...
</v-dialog>
```

Check [this Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-71687507-153esd) I made as demo.

---

You also have some doubts about the documentation of `width` and `max-width`.  So let's check sources!

Take a look at [VDialog.ts](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VDialog/VDialog.ts#L298). You can see that some **convertToUnit** function is applied for both `width` and `max-width` properties when the component is created.

Then take a look at **convertToUnit** definition at [helpers.ts](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/util/helpers.ts#L188). There's no magic here. It just applies Numbers like 500 or Strings like "500" (that is converted to "500px"), "700px", "100%", ... . You can also put any of special CSS keywords that are allowed for width/max-width CSS property. They are listed [here at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#syntax).